# Extract HTML table for UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, html-content-extraction

I am trying to make a UITableView based application for the iPhone.  I have done this before by extracting data from RSS feeds, but for this application I am trying to use data from a webpage.  The data is in a web table format (http://www.roblox.com/Forum/Default.aspx), and has different hierarchies because it is a forum.

How should I go about parsing this data?  Is there a framework I can use?

Once again, the data I would like to use is the table (forum) at this website - http://www.roblox.com/Forum/Default.aspx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend [Hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple). It's a really good XML/HTML parser.

To use it, you'll need to add `${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2` in "Header Search Path", in your project option and add `-lxml2` to "Other Linker Flag".

Then, drag it to your code: `TFHpple.h`, `TFHpple.m`, `TFHppleElement.h`, `TFHppleElement.m`, `XPathQuery.h`, `XPathQuery.m`.

In the code add:

```
NSData *htmlData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.roblox.com/Forum/Default.aspx"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//a[@class='forumTitle']"];

for(int i = 0; i < [elements count]; i++) {
    TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *string = [element content];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}

[xpathParser release];
[htmlData release];
```

We made a loop in every `a` with `class = forumTitle` with `TFHppleElement` and `NSLog` it.

To understand more, take a look at [XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp). Also check [a tutorial](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/02/24/parsing-html-iphone-development/).

Now you ask: Why use Hpple? It's faster, more easy to use and with awesome tutorials.

Hope it help!

Comment: Thank you!  This seems to be what I was looking for, and I will test it out.

Comment: You're welcome. If you're having trouble parsing some element with XPath Sintax, comment here that I'll help you.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ran into an error.  I was looking at the tutorial, and it keeps crashing at this line - NSData *htmlData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.objectgraph.com/contact.html"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Now I notice that that link is not valid, sorry.